# Installing ICU libraries and compiling program

Tags: c++, icu

I'm exploring using IBM's ICU to work with Unicode strings, by writing sample code.

Following the steps from ICU's [page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icufaq#TOC-How-do-I-install-the-binary-versions-of-ICU-), I unpacked the contents of icu4c-57_1-RHEL6-x64.tgz onto /usr/local/include and /usr/local/bin, on my Linux box. Would this suffice for one to start using the ICU library?

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include "unicode/coll.h"
#include "unicode/utypes.h"

using namespace icu;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UErrorCode success = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    Collator *collator = Collator::createInstance(success);
    collator->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);

    if (collator->compare("débárquér", "debarquer") == 0) {
        cout << "Strings are equal" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Strings are unequal" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation of this code fails:

```
$ g++ unicode.cc
/tmp/ccUknunM.o: In function `main':
unicode.cc:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::Collator::createInstance(UErrorCode&)'
unicode.cc:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const*)'
unicode.cc:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const*)'
unicode.cc:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
unicode.cc:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
unicode.cc:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
unicode.cc:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `icu_4_2::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From the output, it appears that ICU installation is either incorrect or incomplete. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Edit:

When I search for the file coll.h, this is what I see:

```
$ find /usr/local/ -name coll.h
/usr/local/bin/usr/local/include/unicode/coll.h
/usr/local/include/usr/local/include/unicode/coll.h
```

Does this look alright?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the path of the header files? g++ -I/usr/local/include unicode.cc

Comment: I tried that, but same result.

Comment: coll.h is located in unicode folder. Try #include <unicode/coll.h>

Comment: I think the path should be /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/include. Besides, it seems Collator is in icu namespace.

Comment: Any particular reason why you did not use your system's package manager to install ICU, which would have set up everything ready-to-go (**and** would keep updating the package alongside with everything else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "steps from the ICU page" state that...

> ...the .tgz file unpacks to a "/usr/local" type hierarchy.

Looking at the archive contents...

```
$ tar tzf icu4c-57_1-RHEL6-x64.tgz
readme.txt
usr/
usr/local/
usr/local/lib/
usr/local/lib/libicudata.so.57.1
usr/local/lib/libicudata.so
usr/local/lib/libicudata.so.57
...
```

...you are supposed to extract that archive to **root** (`/`), not once to `/usr/local/bin` and once to `/usr/local/include` as you did. (The path repetition in your `find` results should have been a hint. No, it does not look alright at all.)

---

That being said, what you *really* should have done is checking your distribution's package manager for the ICU packages (`libicu`, `libicu-dev`, ...). Installing via your package manager has several advantages:

- It avoids problems like the one you just encountered.
- It ensures that the version of ICU *you* are using for your programs is the same as used by other package's programs; ending up with a binary that links two *different* versions of the ICU libraries is just asking for trouble.
- It keeps the package updated automatically.

Depending on your distribution, you might not get the absolute latest release, but that does usually not matter much.

---

Once you *have* a functioning installtion, third-party frameworks commonly require you to explicitly state an `include/` subdirectory, either in the source or the build file, to make it clear which framework(s) you are actually using. For ICU, the prefix is (somewhat unintuitively) `unicode`... and they don't make this explicit in their documentation, where it reads...

```
#include <unistr.h>
```

So, if you instead write...

```
#include "unicode/coll.h"
```

...it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I installed `libicu.i686` and `libicu-devel.x86_64` packages via `yum install`, but couldn't get past the compilation error. The header file `coll.h` is available under `/usr/include/unicode/`

Comment: @Maddy: Sorry, hadn't looked beyond the borked installation. Answer updated.

Comment: That solved the header file issue. But facing other compilation issues: `$ g++ unicode.cc
unicode.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
unicode.cc:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
unicode.cc:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘collator’ to be of abstract type ‘icu_4_2::Collator’
/usr/include/unicode/coll.h:177: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘icu_4_2::Collator’:
/usr/include/unicode/coll.h:770: note:  virtual void* icu_4_2::Collator::getDynamicClassID() const ...`

Comment: @Maddy: Follow the breadcrumbs: [ICU homepage](http://site.icu-project.org/) -- [API Reference Index](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) -- [`icu::Collator`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1Collator.html), reading "The Collator class performs locale-sensitive string comparison. [More...](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1Collator.html#details)", with the link leading you to a detailed description on how to use it. Yes, I just told you to read the fine documentation.

Comment: I changed the code to factor in what the document says, but continue to face issues. The latest code and the compilation/linker error are now part of the original post.

Comment: @Maddy: What you **didn't** do in all that time was giving an upvote, marking this answer as being the one that correctly answered the original question, and/or post a new question. I got the example to work within two minutes. You can solve your problem on your own for all I care at this point.

Comment: The upvote and acceptance of the answer was definitely in order, but I was more focused on getting this to work. Anyway, thanks, again for all the help thus far!

Comment: @Maddy: Thanks, and excuse the grumpiness. You basically asked three completely unrelated (and pretty basic) questions in a row: installation, using an API correctly, and now linker problems. You need to link the appropriate libs -- `-licuuc -licui18n` in this case.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @Maddy: ICU is a core library in my 9-to-5 job, so... yeah. You're welcome. ;-)

Comment: Would it be alright if I contacted you offline (via email) with all things ICU?

Comment: @Maddy: I'd rather you didn't. SO questions I can answer or not depending on whether I habe the time. If you mail me, it's my responsibility to reply.